# Exporting country's border coordinates

Tags: polygon, coordinates

I have downloaded QGIS with the hopes of being able to obtain a polygon that closely represents a country's border. I was thinking I should be able to obtain x number of vertices that form the border of a country, but so far I've only been able to obtain the area of the country. I've heard people referencing Natural Earth and other sources, but from those I have only found these areas. Is there a way to obtain what I am looking for?

For reference, my goal is to then export this list of coordinates and import it into a JAVA IDE.

Answer (score 2):

1. [Extract vertices](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisextractvertices) to make each vertex a point
2. [Add geometry attributes](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisexportaddgeometrycolumns) to add x and y coordinates to the points.

Then you can right-click the output and save as whatever file format you want.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That works. Do you know if it would be possible to remove islands?

Comment: You can [extract by expression](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisextractbyexpression) polygons with an area above some value. `$area>50000`

Comment: One last thing. You mentioned on step 2 above how to obtain the x-y coordinates. Is there a similar tool for obtaining the GCS latitude /longitude coordinates?

Comment: You can [reproject](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisreprojectlayer) the layer prior to add geometry attributes. To for example EPSG:4326

Comment: Got it! Thank you very much for your help, now hoping my JAVA script won't implode with all these vertices.

Comment: Nice! You can reduce the vertice count with [Simplify](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html?highlight=simplify#simplify), if you dont need the full precision